# How to add checkboxes for a woocommerce product?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a wordpress site that does food catering. I want to be able to do the following configuration when placing an order:

Days: Select the weekdays via checkboxes

Food Options: Select the type of food via radio buttons

Other Options: Other checkboxes for extra options

My idea is to use woocommerce to have 1 product that's configurable with the above options. I looked into variable products, but there's no checkbox options. How to I add checkboxes to a woocommerce product? If that's not possible, are there better recommended options(either via plugins or programatically)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ACF for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-for-woocommerce/) plugin for adding field to Woocommerce.

Comment: This plugin has been removed for guideline violations. There are others available if you search the WordPress plugin store. I found one called "Extra Product Options" but it may not exactly match your requirements.